# Windows handling CTRL+C in different thread?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, qt, signals

Here is a simple application that handled <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> signal both on linux and windows:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

void SigIntHandler()
{
    qDebug()<<"SigInt ThreadID: "<<QThread::currentThreadId();
    qApp->quit();
}

#ifdef __linux__
#include <signal.h>

    void unix_handler(int s)
    {
        //svakako je SIGINT, ali da ne javlja warning da se s ne koristi
        if (s==SIGINT)
            SigIntHandler();
    }

#else
#include <windows.h>

    BOOL WINAPI WinHandler(DWORD CEvent)
    {
        switch(CEvent)
        {
        case CTRL_C_EVENT:
            SigIntHandler();
            break;
        }
        return TRUE;
    }

#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);


    //kod za hvatanje CTRL+C - unix i windows
    #ifdef __linux__
        signal(SIGINT, &unix_handler);
    #else
        SetConsoleCtrlHandler((PHANDLER_ROUTINE)WinHandler, TRUE);
    #endif

    qDebug()<<"Main ThreadID: "<<QThread::currentThreadId();
    return a.exec();
}
```

After compiling and running it on linux (Debian Squeeze), I get following output:

```
/Test-build-desktop$ ./Test 
Main ThreadID:  140105475446560 
^CSigInt ThreadID:  140105475446560 

/Test-build-desktop$ ./Test 
Main ThreadID:  140369579480864 
^CSigInt ThreadID:  140369579480864 

/Test-build-desktop$ ./Test 
Main ThreadID:  140571925509920 
^CSigInt ThreadID:  140571925509920
```

And that's what I've expected (SigIntHandler method runs on main thread). But when I compile and execute same code on Windows 7, I get this:

```
d:\Test-build-desktop\debug>Test.exe
Main ThreadID:  0x5a8
SigInt ThreadID:  0x768

d:\Test-build-desktop\debug>Test.exe
Main ThreadID:  0x588
SigInt ThreadID:  0x1434

d:\Test-build-desktop\debug>Test.exe
Main ThreadID:  0x1170
SigInt ThreadID:  0xc38
```

As you can see, here SigIntHandler method is executed in different thread then main ... And that creates me many problems. So my question is - is it possible to force SigIntHandler to run in main thread on windows ? Am I maybe catching siging wrong ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [MSDN topic HandlerRoutine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683242(v=vs.85).aspx):

A HandlerRoutine function is an application-defined function used with the `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` function. A console process uses this function to handle control signals received by the process. When the signal is received, the system creates a new thread in the process to execute the function.

So, the answer is: this is impossible.

Comment: uf ... Microsoft always has to be special :( Thanks for info ;)

Comment: It's not impossible. In the handler routine set by the SetConsoleCtrlHandler function (which is run in a new thread) you could manipulate the main thread using the SetThreadContext function. It’s not for the faint hearted and some assembly knowledge is required, but it’s possible. Not that you’d want things to work the Unix way in this area.

Comment: In fact, Microsoft did this again the correct way. Signals are one of the most sucking features on Unix. No need to define signal async safeness for each function etc. In the end on non trivial programs on unix you regularly end up just increasing a semaphore to run another thread which can do the real work.

Comment: Adding the link as reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683242(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 7):

Read the following link for an interesting take on this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/07/28/8781423.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the comment :) After reading this, it really seems that windows way is a better one ... Anyway, I don't care, I've fixed my program to work booth on linux and windows :)

Comment: That link is dead now. Archive.org has it backed up: https://web.archive.org/web/20140413051550/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/07/28/8781423.aspx